# How to fix Meteor is not an internal or exteral command error in command prompt

Tags: node.js, meteor

I encountered this error for the first time, tried restarting my computer, reinstalling meteor but nothing seems to be working for some reasons, pls how do I fix this?

> Meteor is not an internal or exteral command error in command prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're running `Meteor` on Windows.
You can try two things:
- Run command prompt as an administrator
- Try adding `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\.meteor;` to your PATH.